# doubt in probability formula

Tags: probability

I was reading a book and in that book I found [image]

In this how they have written 2,3&4 formula and what does it signifies.

Comment: Do not copy text from your book, please. It is hard to read. Rewrite it nicely and please clarify what your exact question is, because I really have no idea.

Comment: It's really just a case of inclusion and exclusion, a useful principle of probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"at least two of A,B,C" is $(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)\cup(B\cap C)$, which on the Venn Diagram is the three overlapping lenses (the trefoils). The probability is the sum of the probabilities of each lens excluding the probability of the centre intersection twice (to avoid overcounting the outcomes therein).

$$\small{\mathsf P\big((A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)\cup(B\cap C)\big)}={\mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(A\cap C)+\mathsf P(B\cap C)-2\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C)}$$

"exactly two of A,B,C" is $(A\cap B\cap\overline C)\cup(A\cap\overline B\cap C)\cup(\overline A\cap B\cap C)$, which on the Venn Diagram is the leaves of the trefoils but not the centre intersection.  So its probability is that of the above minus that of the central intersection one more time.

$$\small{\mathsf P\bigl((A\cap B\cap\overline C)\cup(A\cap\overline B\cap C)\cup(\overline A\cap B\cap C)\bigr)}={\mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(A\cap C)+\mathsf P(B\cap C)-3\mathsf P(A\cap B\cap C)}$$

"exactly one" is the entire union minus the trefoils.

$$\small {\mathsf P\bigl((\overline A\cap\overline B\cap C)\cup(\overline A\cap B\cap\overline C)\cup(A\cap\overline B\cap\overline C)\bigr)} = {\mathsf P(A\cup B\cup C)-{\mathsf P\big((A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)\cup(B\cap C)\big)}}$$